# How to update the values to the remaining rows in update statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `Products` like this:

```
   product_id   product_rev  project owning_project
   ----------   ----------   ------  -------------
    1              aaa        p1          p1
    1              baa        null        p1
    1              caa        null        p1
    2              ddd        p2          p2
    2              eee        null        p2  
    2              kkk        null        p2  
    3              fff         p3         p3
    3              ggg         p3         p3
    3              hhh       null         p3
    3              iii       null         p3
    4              zzz       null         p4
    4              ttt        p4          p4
    4              rrr        null        p4
```

For one `product_id`, there can be multiple `product_revid`'s.

I want to update the `owning_project` column as per the above given in the table.

Here for `product_id+product_rev` if project value is there, then it should update the same value for all the remaining which are having null values in the `owning_project` column.

From comments sections, OP states

> i want to update the project column values to the owing_project column as shown in the above. it should update the same project value for all the remaining also which are having null values in the owning_project column

and

> HERE OWNING_PROJECT IS NEW COLUMN WHICH IS HAVING ALL NULL VALUES..AFTER UPDATING IT SHOULD GIVE THE ABOVE RESULTS.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you're asking. What is the sample output you'd expect for the above rows? What have you tried so far?

Comment: here i want to update the project column values to the owing_project column as shown in the above.
it should update the same project value for all the remaining also which are having null values in the owning_project column.

Comment: What does product_id + product_rev have to do with it? Are you just saying you want the project column to be set to that record's owning_project wherever it is NULL?

Answer (score 1):

I think you simply want `coalesce()`

```
update Products
set project  = coalesce(project, owning_project)
--where project is null;
```

you can also simplify as

```
update Products
set project  = owning_project
where project is null;
```

**EDIT :**

```
update p
set owning_project = (select MAX(project) from Products where product_id = p.product_id)
from Products p;
```

Comment: HERE OWNING_PROJECT IS NEW COLUMN WHICH IS HAVING ALL NULL VALUES..AFTER UPDATING IT SHOULD GIVE THE ABOVE RESULTS..

Comment: @badri... Then update `owning_project` column. see edit.

Answer (score 1):

Following simple query should work for you.

```
update t 
set    [owning_project] = 
                (select top 1 [project] 
                from   Products  t2 
                where  t2.product_id = t.product_id 
                      and t2.[project]  is not null ) 
from   Products  t
```

**<kbd>[DEMO](http://rextester.com/KHLW38604)</kbd>**

Answer (score 0):

You can try a query like below.

**TO NOTE:**
OP mentioed in comments

> i want to update the project column values to the owing_project column as shown in the above. it should update the same project value for all the remaining also which are having null values in the owning_project column

The answer does not satisfy this comment.
From another comment

> HERE OWNING_PROJECT IS NEW COLUMN WHICH IS HAVING ALL NULL VALUES..AFTER UPDATING IT SHOULD GIVE THE ABOVE RESULTS.
>   This answer is as per original question and this comment.

```
update t1
set t1.owning_project= t.project
from
tbl t1 join 
(
select 
max(project) as project,
product_id    
from
tbl group by product_id
) t
on t1.product_id    =t.product_id
```